# How to extract data from a website in VB.net using XPATH or other techniques?

Tags: vb.net, xpath, web

I am trying to write a simple app in VB.net to gather information from a website and then have the app email the results to me. The purpose is to gather page counts from a printer when the toner is changed. I have the XPATH of the data I need, but I have not been able to figure out how to use this in VB. (I have very little experience programming).

So far I have the app logging into the printer portal and displaying the webpage that has the information I need. The XPATH for this info is:

//*[@id="contents"]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td

Can anyone help me extract and parse the number out of this table cell?

Thanks for any help you guys can give!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use streamreader! look ath this example:

```
        Dim inStream As StreamReader
        Dim webRequest As WebRequest
        Dim webresponse As WebResponse


        webRequest = webRequest.Create("YOUR URL TO THE PAGE GOES HERE")
        webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
        inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim sourcecode As String = inStream.ReadToEnd()
        Dim x1 As Integer = sourcecode.IndexOf("<td>Nr. of toner changed:") + 25 '25 is the number of characters in the string to search
        Dim x2 As Integer = sourcecode.IndexOf("times </td>") 'what comes right after your search string. has to be unique in the page

        dim nuberofchanges as integer = sourcecode.Substring(x1, x2 - x1)
```

hope this helps! :)